# Enable nested virtualization on Windows 10 Hyper-V for the root OS

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtualization, hyper-v

Is it possible to enable nested virtualization for Windows 10 Hyper-V, for the root environment? The root Windows environment cannot run other virtualization software like VMWare without it.

Comment: Can you please update your hardware details.

Comment: @vembutech What does my hardware have to do with whether or not a product has a feature?

Answer (score -2):

Three is possible to [enable nested virtualization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization) on exact stopped machine by PowerShell command with Administrator privileges:

```
Set-VMProcessor -VMName deb9 -ExposeVirtualizationExtensions $true
```

where `deb9` is a stopped virtual machine name which can be taken from Hyper-V management console:
[image: hyper-v]

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to do this for the root environment.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer could you please explain what is "root environment" for you?

Comment: The root environment is Windows 10 w/ Hyper-V.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer so command line in my answer is doing exactly this. You have host OS(root environment is Windows 10 w/ Hyper-V) which has VMs which has option `ExposeVirtualizationExtensions` and this option have to be set to enable nested virtualization fo this VM

Comment: @DavidPfeffer VMware doesn't work in same time with Hyper-V, because of Guard Credentials https://communities.vmware.com/thread/600620

Comment: It doesn't seem like your command line is doing this. What name would you use in place of `deb9` for the root environment?

Comment: @DavidPfeffer It's not a my command, it's a command from MS docs, and it's enables nested virtualization for specified VM, check answer again for more details.

Comment: You aren't answering the question. What name would you use for the *root* environment?

Comment: If you are unfamiliar with Hyper-V architecture, see: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/reference/hyper-v-architecture